# stroke is not in middle in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to draw an arrow in photoshop to point something. But the stroke (Blue line, like pen tool path) is in a the side not in the middle. Can I put it in the middle like I can in Illustrator?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've drawn a shape, and applied a stroke, then Switch to the Direct Selection tool <kbd>A</kbd>, and make sure the shape layer is selected. You can then change the stroke alignment to *centre* in the Stroke Type dropdown.

[image]